# Cannot connect to docker-compose services in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run Cypress e2e tests by spinning up docker-compose services and checking them with Cypress. What ever I do, I am not able to connect to another service either outside of the service or inside of one.

I tried adding running `curl 127.0.0.1` to check if service is reachable, but it returns "*Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused*"

My CodeBuild environment has privileged set to true.

This is my buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Test Execution starting...
      - AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID 
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - docker-compose --file=deployment/docker.yml up -d main webserver
      - docker-compose --file=deployment/docker.yml run cypress
    
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker-compose --file=deployment/docker.yml down
```

My docker-compose file is very simple. It get's images that have already been built.

```
version: '3'
services: 
  main: 
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/main:${ENVIRONMENT}
    build: 
      context: ../main
    container_name: main
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - network
  
  webserver: 
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/webserver:${ENVIRONMENT}
    build: 
      context: ../frontend
    container_name: webserver
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    depends_on: 
      - main
    networks:
      - network

  cypress:
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/cypress:${ENVIRONMENT}
    build: 
      context: ../cypress
    command: "--browser chrome"
    depends_on: 
      - webserver
      - main
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://webserver:80
    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: anyone on this? I have the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My cypress instance wasn´t able to connect with the service to test.

I solved it setting "network_mode" to "host" and the base url to "localhost" in the cypress service.

In your case, it would be something similar to this:

```
  cypress:
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/cypress:${ENVIRONMENT}
    build: 
      context: ../cypress
    command: "--browser chrome"
    depends_on: 
      - webserver
      - main
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://localhost:80
    network_mode: "host"
```